# Connect Power BI with mith MySQL of shared database

Tags: powerbi

There is a database in PHP which is not hosted on a local machine.
I want to connect the database to Power BI.

The error is:

> MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

The MySQL connector is already installed.

Here is the proof:

[image]

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eatj.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, if it is the first time you are connecting to it, then you can see an icon at the home page called MySQL. Then click on it and it will ask for details. It will ask for the server name. Enter the name and database if required. Then it verifies and asks for the username and password to login.

The server IP address in your image is IP address 54.90.3.4. This is your hosted server.

If your database is hosted on same server, you should set your same server value.

Add the default localhost in the last.

[Follow here to connect your server to power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKONB.png)